# Could not connect to database server

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I moved my webpage from old system to new and I have now problem with connection to database. Versions are: Mysql 5.1.67 and phpMyadmin 3.4.3.2. Where is the problem?

on website:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/do031500/www_root/lib/database.inc.php on line 13
>   Could not connect to database server

database.inc.php:

```
class CDatabase {

public  $Connected  = false;
private $Mysqli;
public  $Result;

// Connect to database server
function Connect() {
    global $DatabaseSupport;
    if ($DatabaseSupport) {
    $this->Mysqli = new mysqli(dbServer, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDatabase);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        $this->Connected    = false;
        Terminate("Could not connect to database server");
        } else { 
        $this->Connected    = true;
        $this->Mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
        $this->Mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    }
    }
}

// Disconnect from server
function Disconnect() {
    if ($this->Connected) {
        $this->Mysqli->close();
    }
}

// Execute query
function Query($Query) {
    $this->Result   = false;
    if ($this->Connected) {
            $this->Result = $this->Mysqli->query($Query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
        if (!$this->Result) 
        Terminate('Invalid query: '.$this->Mysqli->error);
        }
    return $this->Result;
}

// Close query query
function Close($Datalink) {
    if ($this->Connected) {
    mysqli_free_result($Datalink);
        }
}

// Commit
function Commit() {
    if ($this->Connected)
    $this->Mysqli->Commit();
}

// Rollback
function Rollback() {
    if ($this->Connected) 
    $this->Mysqli->Rollback();
}

// GetRecordCount
function RecordCount($DataLink) {
    if ($this->Connected) 
            return $DataLink->num_rows;
    else
    return 0;
}

// Get last RecordID
function GetLastRecordID() {
    if ($this->Connected) 
            return $this->Mysqli->insert_id;
    else
    return false;
}

// Get next line from query
function GetNextLine($Datalink = NULL) {
    if ($this->Connected) {
            if ($Datalink != NULL) 
            $this->Result = $Datalink;
        return $this->Result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
        }
}

// Execute query and return first line
function QueryFirstLine($Query) {
    if ($this->Connected) {
            if ($this->Result = $this->Query($Query))
            return $this->Result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
        }
}

// GetField list for current query
function GetFieldList($Datalink = NULL) {
    if ($this->Connected) {
            if ($Datalink != NULL) 
            $this->Result = $Datalink;
            //$FieldsCount = $this->Result->field_count;
    $List = NULL;
    while ($Finfo = $this->Result->fetch_field()) {
            $List[] = $Finfo->name;
    }
        return $List;
        }
}

// encode value
function EncodeValue($Value) {
    return $Value;
}

// move item
function MoveItem($SQL, $RecordID, $Forward, $TableName) {
    $Query = $this->Query($SQL);
    while ($Line = $this->GetNextLine($Query)) {
            $List[] .= $Line['RecordID'];
    }
    $HasMove = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($List); $i++) {
    if ((!$HasMove) && ($List[$i] == $RecordID)) {
        if ($Forward) {
        if ($i < count($List)-1) {
            $a = $List[$i+1];
            $List[$i+1] = $List[$i];
            $List[$i] = $a;
            $i++;
        }
        } else {
        if ($i > 0) {
            $a = $List[$i-1];
            $List[$i-1] = $List[$i];
            $List[$i] = $a;
        }
        }
        $HasMove = true;
    }

    }

    $cnt = 1;
        foreach ($List as $Key=>$Value) {
        $this->Query("update $TableName set OrderNo='".$cnt."' where RecordID='$Value'");
    $cnt++;
    }
        $this->Commit();
}


}
```

Comment: `dbServer` is not a valid PHP variable. use `$`

Comment: Hey, there was not problem. Problem was that I had update infomation about DB server in document with address of dbserver, username, password. Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

Initial thought would be due to one of your connection variables.  Have you double-checked that you have all of your new server's info right?  server, port, username, password, database, table?

Comment: I have server address, username, database and table but do I need update there somewhere? Or it is automaticly? (different password between old and new DB)

Comment: Yes...if the password to your mysql server is different between servers, you need to update them.  I have no idea where you are setting these variables in your program (dbServer, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDatabase), but they will need to be changed if the settings are different on your new server.

Comment: I found it. Thanks for help

Comment: No problem...if the answer helped, please mark it as accepted so that others no how to fix their issues.